# Remove dynamic columns added to HTML table with this.closest

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table I am adding columns to dynamically. Each input column added also has a check mark to continue  adding it and an x mark to remove it. The remove function is not working as I am trying to remove the closest td but then all of the added input columns are removed when I click on the x mark. How do I make it so just the selected dynamic column is removed? Here is what I have

```
var myform = $('#myform'),
     iter = 0;
 $('#btnAddCol').click(function () {
     myform.find('tr').each(function(){
       var trow = $(this);
         if(trow.index() === 0){
             trow.append('<td><input type="text" id="input"><input type="image" src="checkmark.png" name="accept" class="accept" id="accept" /><input type="image" src="xmark.png" name="cancel" class="cancel" id="cancel" /></td>');
         }

     });
     iter += 1;
 });

  $('#cancel').click(function () {
    $(this).closest("td").find('.input').remove();
 });
```

Comment: When you say column do you mean a cell `<td>` or a group of cells stacked vertically?

Comment: Sorry meant to say a specific cell that is a column header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code you seem to be appending a cell(TD element) to a table row(TR) of the table.

To remove the cell (or any element within that cell) you can pass the element(this) that was clicked to a function like this:

```
<input type="button" value="cancel" id="cancel" onClick="removeCell(this)" />
```

and then define a new function that will remove the parent element(the TD element in this case) or a different element within the cell like this:

```
function removeCell(clickedElement) {
  // select the parent element(td element) of the cancel button, and remove it
  $(clickedElement.parentElement).remove();
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/arb7dt35/2/)